# WPF. RadGridView. How can I know which column is selected(sorting)? CurrentColumn binding doesn't work

Tags: wpf, radgridview

How can I know which column is selected(sorting)? CurrentColumn binding doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CurrentColumn represent the column of the currently selected cell.

If you want to know which column is used for sorting\filtering in the `RadGridView` I suggest binding to a `QueryableCollectionView` (also telerik class) and this exposes a set of `SortDescriptors` or `FilterDescriptors`

If you're using the MVVM pattern the QueryableCollectionView can be exposes as property for your ViewModel and then you can manipulate the filtering and sorting away from the View.

```
public class ExampleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ExampleChildViewModel> _items;
    private readonly QueryableCollectionView _filteredItems;

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        _items = new RadObservableCollection<ExampleChildViewModel>();
        _filteredItems = new QueryableCollectionView(_items);

        // todo - fill the items...
    }

    public IEnumerable Items { get { return _filteredItems; } }
}
```

If you're not using MVVM you can just mash it into the code-behind with the rest of the code :)

Comment: Thanks. I used SortDescriptions property of CollectionView to obtain column name.